# Nagging app for tasks without due dates

Tags: task-management

Many tasks have clear and definitive due dates, like paying bills.

However most of my tasks don’t have due dates. Examples are washing my car, painting my house, calling to book a health check. As I put off doing them, their urgency gets higher.

I’ve been searching in vain for an app that can handle tasks without due dates and nag me more and more as tasks are left undone. Do you know of any?

Comment: "App" means what: Android, iOS, WebApp …? And is there a budget you'd be willing to spend, or must it come for free?

Comment: This would probably be a service running in the cloud with web UI or apps for major smartphone operating systems. Free is preferable.

Comment: So what is it you require? "probably" and "major" are a bit vague here. You certainly won't object if it supports more devices than you need – but certainly will if yours is not supported :) So do you *need* it being a cloud service, or would a local app for e.g. Android also be acceptable?

Comment: @Izzy: Android, iOS or a web interface is fine with me. I don't think there is a program for this that you install locally, which would come with a database and only be accessible locally unless you set up your own web server. That's why, if it exists, it is likely to be hosted as a web service, like Trello, VersionOne or similar.

Comment: If it's *your* tasks, that could well be handled locally. If your requirement is to have it available on multiple devices synchronously, you most likely will need some server part (unless sync is done P2P). As you didn't specify what you need, it's hard to tell. But OK, I will stop nagging you about it (especially as I couldn't name a fitting app anyway). Good luck then!